# ActiveMQ: how to define subscribers for durable topic

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I would like to spread some data from a "master" to 3-5 subscribers, and I need to be sure they get all messages. I could do this by creating a queue for each subscriber, but can I achieve that through topic? Can I define, that Topic **must** keep the message, until all predefined subscribers acknowledge it?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, sounds like durable subscribers :)

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/1_3_1-fcs/doc/basics.html

Comment: Yep, after reading it closer it may be it (or rather: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/1_3_1-fcs/doc/advanced.html#1024758). Thanks :)